# Representations of Banach algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-algebras

If $A$ is a Banach algebra and $L$ a left ideal of $A$, consider the representation $T_{L}$ of $A$ into the algebra $B(A/L)$ of bounded linear operators on the quotient space $A/L$ defined by $T_{L}(a)(b+L)=ab+L$. When is $T_{L}(A)$ closed in the norm of $B(A/L)$? Certainly this happens if $A/L$ is finite-dimensional. Are there other cases? Thanks, Paul.

Comment: How did this question arise?

Comment: I am currently studying the invariant subspaces of strictly cyclic Banach algebras and their reflexivity (as operator algebras).

Comment: Well, it would be easy to give examples. In "reasonable" cases the kernel of $T_L$ is $L$ and the norm of $T_L(a)$ equals the norm of $a + L$ in $A/L$. So $T_L(A)$ is isometric to $A$ and therefore complete. There will be degenerate examples where that isn't true, though. A good question would be: is $T_L(A)$ always closed?

Comment: Thanks, but I do not know when this happens in general. It may happen even if the norms are not equal.

Comment: The kernel is a two sided ideal, cannot equal L (a left ideal),

Comment: In case $A$ is a C*-algebra and $L$ is a closed left ideal, $T_L(A)$ is isometrically isomorphic to the C*-algebra $A/\ker T_L$. I guess it's not that simple for general Banach algebras.

Comment: Thanks Narutaka. I need these facts for more general Banach algebras. I could assume a little more: what if L is a maximal left ideal?

Comment: T_L (A) is not in general a C*-algebra even if A is. Am I missing something? Thanks Narutaka.